# Given a linear transformation and a matrix, how does one determine if the matrix is in the range of T?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve a problem like the one posted below but im having trouble understanding.

[image]

Comment: Huh?  A matrix represents a transformation; it can't be in the range of a transformation.

Comment: Why not? It only has to be linear like $T(\lambda A + \mu B) = \lambda T(A) + \mu T(B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting the comparison $T(X)$ vs $A$ from the lower right:
$$
b = 0 \\
a = 1 \\
d = -1 \\
-5 = -1 + 2c \iff c=-2
$$
Then the upper elements are $-1$ and $-1$ which fits!
$$
X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So $A = T(X) \in R(T)$.

Comment: I understand how you got the values of a,b,c and d, but what do you mean by the upper elements are -1 and -1 and also is the matrix A determined to be in R(T) because it has a solution?